# Optimal stopping (reference request)

Tags: dynamic-programming

I am interested in the following optimal stopping problem:

- On each day, a number $a_i$ is drawn from a (possibly fixed) distribution.
- I can either stop now, getting a payoff of $a_i$, or wait for a later
  draw.
- In principle, this could go on forever. However, future payoffs are
  discounted at a (possibly constant) rate.

I know this kind of problem has been analysed extensively. Can anyone recommend some references on how one characterises optimal strategies in this context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known as the McCall search model in economics. The original paper shows that the optimal stopping strategy rule is given by a "reservation wage", there is a threshold such that it is optimal to accept any draw above this threshold:

McCall, John J. "[The economics of information and optimal stopping rules](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2351065)." *The Journal of Business* 38.3 (1965): 300-317.

Comment: Thanks for this! Are there any textbooks on this that you especially recommend?

Comment: I don't have any special recommendations, but the book "Recursive Macroeconomic Theory" by Ljungqvist and Sargent discusses the model.